# How do I fix "MiniflareCoreError [ERR_RUNTIME_FAILURE]: The Workers runtime failed to start" error in CloudFlare Wrangler?

Tags: cloudflare, cloudflare-workers, wrangler

I have a project with CloudFlare Workers and I use their Wrangler CLI tool to test them locally. I'm working in a WSL2 environment; Ubuntu 22.04 with Windows 11 as the host.

I had an error in my code that caused Wrangler to crash and exit immediately; no graceful shutdown. When I restarted it, I got the following error and my workers would no longer run.

> MiniflareCoreError [ERR_RUNTIME_FAILURE]: The Workers runtime failed to start

How can I fix this error so that Wrangler will start properly again?

Answer (score -2, accepted):

Since I'm in a Linux environment in WSL2, I was able to run the following command to kill the worker daemon.

```bash
killall workerd
```

According to [this post](https://community.cloudflare.com/t/error-miniflarecoreerror-err-runtime-failure-when-starting-cloudflare-pages-locally-with-wrangler/559600/5) on the CloudFlare forums, this should also work in MacOS.

Comment: I have the same error.
The error persists after running this command.
`killall workerd` <br />
How can I fix this kind of error?

Comment: I also get this error on my macos machine. Works nicely on my ubuntu machine.

Comment: @LarryNeil what OS are you running in?